# How to differentiate between "Black" and "ActiveCaptionText"

Tags: c#, system.drawing

```
void Main()
{
    (Color.FromName("Black").ToArgb() == Color.FromName("ActiveCaptionText").ToArgb()).Dump();
    //                           TRUE ^
}
```

This is a piece of code runned in LINQPad.
Is there a way to differentiate between these two colors ?

Context: I receive the colors in their `int` representation. For example `Black` is `-16777216`. I use this enum from `System.Drawing` namespace called `KnownColor` to get the name of it.

Comment: You can use `IsSystemColor` property to differentiate them. "Black" isn't system color, "ActiveCaptionText" is. Or compare not `ToArgb()` values, but `Color` structs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the name of a given color value, then use the [`ColorTranslator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromwin32?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) class which uses an internal *known color table* to set the `Name` property of the [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netframework-4.8) struct.

**Example**

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Color.FromArgb(-16777216).Name);

// Prints: ff000000
// Whereas...

Console.WriteLine(ColorTranslator.FromWin32(-16777216).Name);

// Prints: Black
```