# How to convert a Color to KnownColor name?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

tried this:

in the `List<Color>` colors there are many different colors over `39,000` and the first item for example is:

`{Name = ffcecece, ARGB = (255, 206, 206, 206)}`

and now I want to convert the ARGB to `KnownColor` name for example if it was Blue or Red or any color name.

the problem is that the method `GetKnownColorName` return only `"Unknown"`.

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(colorsAdded)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < colors.Count; i++)
        {
            colorsNames.Add(GetKnownColorName(colors[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the conversion:

```
private string GetKnownColorName(Color color)
{
    foreach (KnownColor knownColor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
        Color knownColorValue = Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor);

        if (knownColorValue.ToArgb() == color.ToArgb())
        {
            return knownColor.ToString();
        }
    }

    return "Unknown";
}
```

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Colors_Scanner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap imageBitmap;
        private Bitmap imageBitmapComparison;
        private Color currentColor;
        private List<string> colorsNames = new List<string>();
        private List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
        private Bitmap bmp;
        private bool colorsAdded = false; // Flag to track if colors have been added

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Load images into PictureBox controls
            LoadImages();

            // Initialize the bitmap for pictureBox2
            bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
        }

        private void LoadImages()
        {
            // Load an image into the PictureBox control
            imageBitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\Ffmpeg Capture\radar1.jpg"); // Replace with your image
            pictureBox1.Size = imageBitmap.Size;
            pictureBox1.Image = imageBitmap;

            imageBitmapComparison = new Bitmap(@"D:\Ffmpeg Capture\colorslevels1.jpg"); // Replace with your ruler image
            pictureBox2.Size = imageBitmapComparison.Size;
            pictureBox2.Image = imageBitmapComparison;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsMouseWithinPictureBoxBounds(e.Location, pictureBox1))
            {
                UpdateColorLabel(e.Location);
                currentColor = GetColorAtCursor(e.Location, imageBitmap);
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(currentColor);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 3, 3));

            if (!colorsAdded)
            {
                // Add colors from pictureBox2 only once
                AddColorsFromPictureBox2();
                colorsAdded = true; // Set the flag to true after adding colors
            }
        }

        private List<Color> AddColorsFromPictureBox2()
        {
            if (bmp != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
                {
                    if (i == bmp.Width - 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
                    {
                        Color c = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                        // You can add the color to your list here
                        colors.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }

            return colors;
        }

        private void UpdateColorLabel(Point location)
        {
            Color color = GetColorAtCursor(location, imageBitmap);
            label1.Text = $"RGB: ({color.R}, {color.G}, {color.B})";
            label1.BackColor = color;
        }

        private Color GetColorAtCursor(Point location, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            int x = location.X;
            int y = location.Y;

            if (IsMouseWithinPictureBoxBounds(location, pictureBox1))
            {
                BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

                try
                {
                    int bytesPerPixel = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
                    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                    int pixelOffset = y * bmpData.Stride + x * bytesPerPixel;

                    byte b = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset);
                    byte g = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 1);
                    byte r = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, pixelOffset + 2);

                    return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                }
                finally
                {
                    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                }
            }

            return Color.Black; // Default color if outside of PictureBox bounds
        }

        private bool IsMouseWithinPictureBoxBounds(Point location, PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            return location.X >= 0 && location.X < pictureBox.Width && location.Y >= 0 && location.Y < pictureBox.Height;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(colorsAdded)
            {
                for(int i =0; i < colors.Count; i++)
                {
                    colorsNames.Add(GetKnownColorName(colors[i]));
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetKnownColorName(Color color)
        {
            foreach (KnownColor knownColor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
            {
                Color knownColorValue = Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor);

                if (knownColorValue.ToArgb() == color.ToArgb())
                {
                    return knownColor.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what `value` method `GetKnownColorName(value)` returns `"Unknown"` and what you expect it to return? Try [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7brfa)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. How are you creating the `color` you are searching? Are you sure it's alpha value is 255 instead of 0?

Comment: those are the known colors: https://pastebin.com/ALfPvDfp - as you can see the color you are looking for isn't available

Comment: where are those `39,000` colors coming from? .net only knows `174` colors

Comment: @Charlieface `ToKnownColor()` might return 0 even if ARGB values match.

Comment: @Charlieface read the documentation you've linked to. If a color wasn't created with `FromKnownColor()` or `FromName()` then its `IsKnowColor` property won't be `true` and `ToKnownColor()` will return `0` regardless of ARGB values.

Comment: Try the `ColorTranslator` class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945569/14171304 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get closest `KnownColor` for an arbitrary `Color` you have to define some `Distance` method and then you can *query* for known color with minimum distance from `originalColor`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

Color originColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 206, 206);

// Simplest, but not necessary the best one
static int Distance(Color left, Color right) =>
  Math.Abs(left.R - right.R) +
  Math.Abs(left.G - right.G) +
  Math.Abs(left.B - right.B) +
  Math.Abs(left.A - right.A);

var result = Enum
  .GetValues<KnownColor>()
  .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome (note, that `LightGray` is `{255, 211, 211, 211}`):

```
LightGray
```

If you have *custom* collection of known colors, you can organize it as a `Dictionary<Color, string>`, e. g.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Color, string> KnownColors = new() {
  { Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255), "Black Color"},
  { Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 206, 206), "Light Gray Color"},
  // etc.
};
```

Then

```
if (KnownColors.TryGetValue(originColor, out string name)) {
  // originColor is known under "name" name
  Console.Write(name);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/05hVFs)

**Edit:** You can exclude `SystemColors` such as `ActiveBorder` if you like:

```
private static HashSet<string> SystemColorsNames() => typeof(SystemColors)
  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
  .Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
  .Select(prop => prop.Name)
  .ToHashSet();

...

var exclude = SystemColorsNames();  
      
var result = Enum
  .GetValues<KnownColor>()
  .Where(color => !exclude.Contains(Enum.GetName(color)))   
  .MinBy(color => Distance(Color.FromKnownColor(color), originColor));
```

Comment: getting error on that part:  GetValues<KnownColor>  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0308 The non-generic method 'Enum.GetValues(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments Colors Scanner D:\Csharp Projects\Colors Scanner\Form1.cs 154 Active

Comment: @Sharon Leni: https://dotnetfiddle.net/05hVFs

Comment: ah I see `ActiveBorder` what a nice color, next time I want to paint my walls going to tell the painter I want my walls in `ActiveBorder` and see what happens :D - joke aside I doubt that this really is a satistying answer

Comment: @Rand Random: You can *exclude* System Colors if you like (see my edit); I've edited the fiddle as well.